# Low priority keyboard shortcuts

Tags: linux, gnome, mate

I have some keyboard shortcuts set to F11 and F12.

Some applications have their own unchangeable shortcuts for the same keys.

Is there a way to set my shortcuts to have lower priority? In such a way, when the focus is on the application with the conflicting shortcuts, they will be caught by it, when is on other applications, they will keep my behaviour.